# SQL Join on split?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'd like to perform a join on a column which contains a value I would like to split on. So if the column contained email addresses I would like to join on the part before the "@" symbol.

I have seen the split function, but I didnt see anywhere I could choose which array element to pick from the result of the split?

So something like:

```
JOIN ON dbo.split('@',T1.Column)(0)?
```

Comment: Is there a built in split function or did you just write one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're better off just joining on the substring up to the @ symbol:

```
SELECT *
FROM Email 
LEFT JOIN EmailName ON Substring(Email.Address, 1, CharIndex('@', Email.Address) - 1) = EmailName.Name
```

See fiddle here:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5d0f5/8

Comment: I agree.  No point to "split" if only one split is being performed.  But watch out for errors with SUBSTRING caused by values which may not have a "@" at all. One way to avoid this is to pre-SELECT only rows where the column _does_ contain a "@", before the SUBSTRING is applied.

Comment: @sebt - You are absolutely right. I'd be expanding this to cater for null, invalid values etc. and testing accordingly. However I thought it was enough to give my point across.